# BluetoothLeScanner null object reference

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a problem regarding my Bluetooth app. When I enable Bluetooth before starting up the app everything works alright. But when I don't, my app will ask permission to enable Bluetooth via the turnOn method. But when I press my onScan button I get a error stating:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback)' on a null object reference
```

here is my onCreate method:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Set layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Bluetooth
    // BluetoothManager
    final BluetoothManager BTManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    BTAdapter = BTManager.getAdapter();
    // BluetoothLescanner
    BTScanner = BTAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    //Turn on BT
    turnOn();
    //Ask permission for location.
    requestPermission();
}
```

My ques is that, BTScanner is made before the turnOn method is called, making the BTScanner a null object.

Any help regarding this problem would be greatly.

Kind regards,

Binsento

Comment: Have you tried calling `turnOn()` before assigning `BTScanner`?

Comment: Yes I did, i also tried do to a if statement when bluetoothadapter.isEnabled make bluetooothlescanner. But both didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (taken from one of my projects):

Class variable:

```
private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter = null;
```

Inside `onCreate`:

```
final BluetoothManager btManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBtAdapter = btManager.getAdapter();

checkBt(); // called at the end of onCreate
```

The `checkBt()` method:

```
private void checkBt() {
    if (mBtAdapter == null || !mBtAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
}
```

Then from there when the "Scan" button is clicked:

```
public void onScanButton(){
    if (mBtAdapter.isEnabled()){
        scanLeDevice(true);
    }
}
```

Then `scanLeDevice` calls `mBtAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);`

NOTE: Some of this is now deprecated but can be updated to comply with the new API. I have not taken the time to do that.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with my BluetoothAdapter, but with my BluetoothLeScanner called by:         BTScanner = BTAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

Comment: Please check that your `BTScanner` object is not null because your `BTAdapter` is null. In other words, your immediately calling `BTScanner = BTAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();` without checking if you actually have a `BTAdapter`.

Comment: That's what I was trying to show you with my code above.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's exactly what you said. I checked if the scanner wasn't null and then execute the .startscan  with a if statement and put getBleScanner in the else statement with the .startscan statement.

Answer (score -1):

I face the same issue, it bugs me for a long time and I fix it today.

Device: Huawei nonor 8

When I call

```
sLeScanner.stopScan(scanCallback);
sLeScanner.startScan(scanCallback);
```

I got a NullPointerException, the root cause is - sLeScanner == null.

So just add these following code before you start|stop scan:

```
if (sLeScanner == null) sLeScanner = sBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
```

Then fix it.